# When making comparison between the elements in a list, how to efficiently iterate and improve the time complexity from O(n^2)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, data-structures

I have a list where I would like to compare each element of the list with each other. I know we can do that using a nested loop but the time complexity is O(n^2). Is there any option to improve the time complexity and make the comparisons efficient?

**For example:**

I have a list where I would like to find the difference in digits among each element. Consider a list ***array*=[100,110,010,011,100]** where I am trying to find the difference in the digits among each integer. array[0] is same as array[4] (i.e 100 and 100), while array[0] has 1 digit that is different from array[1] (i.e 100 and 110) and array[0] has 3 digits that are different from array[3] (i.e 100 and 011). Assuming similar integers are defined as integers that have either identical or the difference in digits is just 1, I would like to return a list as output,  where every element denotes the integers with similar digits (i.e difference in digits <=1).

For the input list ***array*=[100,110,010,011,100]**, my expected output should be **[2,3,2,1,2]**. In the output list, the output[0] indicates that array[0] is similar to array[1] and array[4] (i.e similar to 100 , we have 2 other integers 110,100 in the list)

This is my code that works, though very inefficient O(n^2):

```
def diff(a,b):
    difference= [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i]!=b[i]]
    return len(difference)

def find_similarity_int(array):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    res=[0]*len(array)
    string=[]
    for n in array:
        string.append(str(n))
    for i in range(0,len(string)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(string)):
            count=diff(string[i],string[j])
            if(count<=1):
                res[i]=res[i]+1
                res[j]=res[j]+1

    return res

input_list=['100','110','010','011','100']
output=find_similarity_int(input_list)
print("The similarity metrics for the given list is : ",output)
```

Output:

> The similarity metrics for the given list is :  [2, 3, 2, 1, 2]

Could anyone please suggest an efficient way to make the comparison, preferably with just 1 loop? Thanks!

Comment: Since you're doing an n*n comparison (by definition you're supposed to compare every element to every other element) it doesn't seem obvious that you'd be able to make it happen faster than n^2.  Does the assignment indicate that you should be able to?  If there's a clever trick here, I'd guess it involves changing the way that you compute `diff` (e.g. somehow doing it digit by digit across the entire list at once instead of element by element).

Comment: There are definitely ways to make the code more elegant --  you could skip the re-conversion to `str`, you could shorten `diff` down to `sum(i != j for i, j in zip(a, b))`, and your main nested loop would look better with `enumerate`.  But none of that changes the time complexity.

Comment: Yes, this question was asked in an Online Assessment but unfortunately, I could not come up with a more efficient solution. How do you do make the comparison digit by digit across the entire list all at once? Any examples?

Comment: I'm envisioning something like summing the occurrences of each digit in each place in O(n), and then using that to somehow deduce (also in O(n)) how similar each string is to everything else in the list.  E.g. there are 3 items with 1 at position 0, so those items differ in that place from 2 other strings.  But I don't think that aggregation trick quite works because you don't know where the differences overlap.

Comment: feels kind of like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values are binary digits only, you can get a O(nxm) solution (where m is the width of the values) using a multiset (Counter from collections).  With the count of values in the multiset, add the counts of items that correspond to exactly one bit change in each number (plus the number of duplicates):

```
from collections import Counter
def simCount(L):
    counts = Counter(L)  # multiset of distinct values / count
    result = []
    for n in L:
        r = counts[n]-1                              # duplicates
        for i,b in enumerate(n):                     # 1 bit changes
            r += counts[n[:i]+"01"[b=="0"]+n[i+1:]]  # count others
        result.append(r)                             # sum of similars
    return result
```

Output:

```
A = ['100','110','010','011','100']

print(simCount(A)) # [2, 3, 2, 1, 2]
```

To avoid the string manipulations on every item, you can convert them to integers and use bitwise operators to make the 1-bit changes:

```
from collections import Counter
def simCount(L):
    bits   = [1<<i for i in range(len(L[0]))] # bit masks
    L      = [int(n,2) for n in L]            # numeric values
    counts = Counter(L)                       # multiset n:count
    result = []
    for n in L:
        result.append(counts[n]-1)            # duplicates
        for b in bits:                        # 1 bit changes
            result[-1] += counts[b^n]         # sum similars
    return result

A = ['100','110','010','011','100']

print(simCount(A)) # [2, 3, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I was just about to post basically the second solution. Though mine was slightly more convoluted as I had not intuited the `counts[b^n]` shortcut.  Nicely done.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot!